# How to restore SQL Server 2014 database backup to a SQL Server 2016?

Tags: sql-server, database-restore

I get backup of my 2014 version database and try to restore this in another server into database with same name and login. This SQL Server version is 2016.

When restoring the backup file, I get this error:

> TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
>
> Restore of database 'TravelEnterDB' failed. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.RelationalEngineTasks)
>
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: BACKUP LOG cannot be performed because there is no current database backup. (Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended)
>
> For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=13.0.16106.4+((SSMS_Rel_16_5).170125-2137)&LinkId=20476

I first created this database in SQL Server 2016 and then tried to restore backup file.

I can restore this backup file in SQL Server 2014 currently.This file has no problem!

What is problem?

[image]

Comment: Do you use option "WITH REPLACE"?

Comment: ok . I use this option. I add image of options to my question

Comment: Uncheck "Tail-log backup" and you'll achieve your goal

Comment: I test this but does not solve

Comment: Which new error message do you get? Could you take a script (the button in the top of the screen) and show us?

Comment: first get error that " System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: The backup set holds a backup of a database other than the existing 'TravelEnterDB' database. (Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended) " and I check " with replace " then get error that " System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: Exclusive access could not be obtained because the database is in use. (Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended) "

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170754/discussion-between-denis-rubashkin-and-programmer138200).

Comment: I've done these steps several times. at the final when open restore wizard and check " with replace "  and uncheck " Tail log backup " restored successfully. please add answer to add vote. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

as noted by hmahdavi this works.
"check " with replace " and uncheck " Tail log backup " restored successfully"